# Can I make this function with HTML5 only?

Tags: javascript, html, function, file, dynamic

I'd like to make a web program with photo editor.

Look at my layout example.
There are 3 type of layout models.

[image]

Each of models have a division area where image will be updating.

1 division model get just one image file only.

2 division one gets 2 images with it.

I'm planning to update image into division area with a masking effect when a user click the division area. It should be having functions of crop, move, reflection, resize...

The result is like the below :
[image]

It is a hard for me to explain details,
But I'm now asking you that Cat it be done by HTML5 only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the layout using CSS3 (search "css clip-path tutorial") and HTML. Photo editing, however, is not natively supported by browsers. You'll have to write your own JavaScript (and leverage other JS libraries) to implement this.